# Package brasero-common needs to be reinstalled

Tags: updates, bug-reporting

When I update/install/un-install any software i get the message:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:The package brasero-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic. Take a look at the [instructions on filing a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Thanks!

Comment: @Lucio Actually, it turns out this sort of thing should *not* be filed as a bug report, and this is perfectly good here. The vast majority of "Please report a bug against the 'update-manager' package..." errors are not bugs at all, but simple configuration problems that are easily fixed. (That it tells people to report a bug ... *that's* a bug...)

Comment: @deepak Please open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Please also run `apt-cache policy brasero-common` and `cat /etc/apt/sources/list`. Then select *all* the text in the Terminal and add it to your question (by editing your question), using the `<$>` tool so it's formatted properly. If it's too much text, please instead paste it at http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the URL that links to it here.